# How to set a related field with a one 2many, many2one and many2many field, using Odoo API(XMLRPC)?

Tags: api, web-services, odoo, xml-rpc

new to Odoo, i'm trying to create a web service in Java, loading data into Odoo, in particular, into the models product.template and technical.sheet, a custom model that i created. For one product there can be 0 or many technical sheets and for one technical sheet - one product.
In the model technical.sheet i created a field x_product_id, the type - many2one and the object relation – product.tamplate. In product.template i create the same field, x_product_id, but the type is one2many, the object relation - technical.sheet and the field relation x_product_id(technical.sheet).
I’ve succeded to load the products and the technical sheets but when I try to set the relational fields, I get errors. 
 Does anybody have an example or an idea how to set  fields of type one2many, many2one and many2many,  using Odoo external API? 
Thanks!
This is the piece of code:

for(Article article: articles.values()) {

```
if(article.getTechSheets().size()>0){
        technicalSheetsMap.put(article.getMfsIdentifier(), article.getTechSheets());
}

ArrayList<Integer> techSheetsIds = new ArrayList<>();

for(TechnicalSheet sh: article.getTechSheets()){
    techSheetsIds.add(Integer.valueOf(sh.getId()));
}

ArrayList<Integer> arrids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arrids.add(Integer.valueOf(article.getMfsIdentifier()));

/* Load of the article into model product.tamplate of the odoo database */
final Integer id = (Integer)models.execute("execute_kw", Arrays.asList(
           db, uid, password,"product.template", "create",
                 Arrays.asList(new HashMap() {{ 
                                               put("is_published", true);
                                               put("active", true);
                                               put("x_standartization_level", article.getStandartizationLevel());
                                               put("id", Integer.valueOf(article.getMfsIdentifier()));
                                               put("default_code", article.getCode());
                                               put("name", article.getLabelEn());
                                               put("x_msf_identifier", article.getMfsIdentifier());
                                               put("display_name", article.getLabelEn());
                                               put("x_label_en", article.getLabelEn());
                                               put("x_oca", article.isOca());
                                               put("x_ocb", article.isOcb());
                                               put("x_ocba", article.isOcba());
                                               put("x_ocg", article.isOcg());
                                               put("x_ocp", article.isOcp());
                                               put("x_cold_chain_group", article.getTermosensitive());
                                               put("x_justification_id", article.getJustificationId());
                                               put("x_transport_un_code_id", article.getTransportUnCodeId());
                                               put("x_picture_content", article.getPictureNb());
                                               put("x_picture_label", article.getPictureLabel());
                                               put("x_controlled_substance", article.getControlledSubstance());
                                               put("x_medical_device_class", article.getMedicalDeviceClass());
                                               put("x_code", article.getCode());
                                               put("x_type", article.getType());
                                               put("x_family_id", article.getFamilyId());
                                               put("x_group_id", article.getGroupId());
                                               put("x_who_id", article.getWhoIds());
                                               put("x_product_id", Integer.valueOf(article.getMfsIdentifier()));
                                                       }})

                  ));



                  for(TechnicalSheet sheet: article.getTechSheets()){


                          final Integer idsh = (Integer)models.execute("execute_kw", Arrays.asList(
                                 db, uid, password,
                               "x_product.technical_sheet", 
                               "create",
                               Arrays.asList(new HashMap(){{    
                                                             put("id", sheet.getId());
                                                             put("x_name", sheet.getLabelEn());
                                                             put("x_description", sheet.getDefinition());
                                                             put("display_name", sheet.getLabelEn());
                                                             put("x_product_id", Integer.valueOf(article.getMfsIdentifier()));
                                                             put("x_norms", sheet.getNorms());
                                                             put("x_precat", sheet.getPrecat());
                                                           }})
                         ));

                  }

          }
```

Comment: hi, welcome on SO, can you update your post by formating nicely the post top ? no paragraph no newlines, this is unlikely someone will read it completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fill or manipulate one2many or many2many field with according values (records) you need to use [special commands](https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/py/x2many.html).

In the following example we add a new order line (`order_line` One2many):

```
main.models.execute("execute_kw", Arrays.asList(
            main.db, uid, main.password,
            "sale.order", "write",
            Arrays.asList(
                Arrays.asList(20),
                new HashMap() {{ 
                        put("order_line", 
                             Arrays.asList(
                                 Arrays.asList(0, 0, 
                                    new HashMap() {{
                                        put("product_id", 3);
                                    }}
                                 )
                             )
                        ); 
                }}
            )
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked. I created list of article (`product.template`), each article is related to zero or many technical sheets (a custom model I created on odoo), relation - one2many.

```
HashMap<String, Article> articles = (HashMap<String, Article>)globalMap.get("articles");
          
String username = "****";
String password = "****";
String db = "****";
String url ="****";

try
{
    final XmlRpcClient authClient = new XmlRpcClient();
    final XmlRpcClientConfigImpl authStartConfig = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
    authStartConfig.setServerURL(new URL(String.format("%s/xmlrpc/2/common", url)));
                  
    List configList = new ArrayList();
    Map paramMap = new HashMap(); 

          configList.add(db);
          configList.add(username);
          configList.add(password);
          configList.add(paramMap);

          int uid = (int)authClient.execute(authStartConfig, "authenticate", configList);

          final XmlRpcClient models = new XmlRpcClient() {{
                      setConfig(new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl() {{
                          setServerURL(new URL(String.format("%s/xmlrpc/2/object", url)));
                      }});
          }};

          /* Loop all the articles */
          for(Article article: articles.values()) {
                   
                  if(article.getTechSheets().size()>0){
                      technicalSheetsMap.put(article.getMfsIdentifier(), article.getTechSheets());
                  }
                     
                  
                  ArrayList<Integer> techSheetsIds = new ArrayList<>();
                  for(TechnicalSheet sh: article.getTechSheets()){
                     techSheetsIds.add(Integer.valueOf(sh.getId()));
                  }
                  
                  
                  ArrayList<Integer> arrids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                  arrids.add(Integer.valueOf(article.getMfsIdentifier()));
                  
                  /* Load of the articles into model product.template of the odoo database */
                  
                  final Integer id = (Integer)models.execute("execute_kw", Arrays.asList(
                        db, uid, password,
                        "product.template", "create",
                        Arrays.asList(new HashMap() {{ 
                                                       put("is_published", true);
                                                       put("active", true);
                                                       put("x_standartization_level", article.getStandartizationLevel());
                                                       put("id", Integer.valueOf(article.getMfsIdentifier()));
                                                       put("default_code", article.getCode());
                                                       put("name", article.getLabelEn());
                                                       put("x_msf_identifier", article.getMfsIdentifier());
                                                       put("display_name", article.getLabelEn());
                                                       put("x_label_en", article.getLabelEn());
                                                       put("x_oca", article.isOca());
                                                       put("x_ocb", article.isOcb());
                                                       put("x_ocba", article.isOcba());
                                                       put("x_ocg", article.isOcg());
                                                       put("x_ocp", article.isOcp());
                                                       put("x_cold_chain_group", article.getTermosensitive());
                                                       put("x_justification_id", article.getJustificationId());
                                                       put("x_transport_un_code_id", article.getTransportUnCodeId());
                                                       put("x_picture_content", article.getPictureNb());
                                                       put("x_picture_label", article.getPictureLabel());
                                                       put("x_controlled_substance", article.getControlledSubstance());
                                                       put("x_medical_device_class", article.getMedicalDeviceClass());
                                                       put("x_code", article.getCode());
                                                       put("x_type", article.getType());
                                                       put("x_family_id", article.getFamilyId());
                                                       put("x_group_id", article.getGroupId());
                                                       put("x_who_id", article.getWhoIds());
                                                       
                                                       /* Set Technical Sheets*/
                                                       if(article.getTechSheets().size()>0){
                                                           put("x_product_id", 
                                                               Arrays.asList(
                                                                    Arrays.asList(
                                                                       0, 
                                                                       0, 
                                                                       new HashMap(){{
                                                                                      for(TechnicalSheet sheet: article.getTechSheets()){
                                                                                          put("id", sheet.getId());
                                                                                          put("x_name", sheet.getLabelEn());
                                                                                          put("x_description", sheet.getDefinition());
                                                                                          put("display_name", sheet.getLabelEn());
                                                                                          put("x_product_id", article.getMfsIdentifier());
                                                                                          put("x_norms", sheet.getNorms());
                                                                                          put("x_precat", sheet.getPrecat());
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        }}
                                                                                        )));
                                                       }}})
                                                       
                  ));
                 
          }
           
          }catch(MalformedURLException e){
              System.out.print("MalformedURLException: "+e.toString()+" "+e.getStackTrace());
          }
          catch(XmlRpcException e){
              System.out.print("XmlRpcException: "+e.toString()+" "+e.getStackTrace());
          }
```